# Que signifie « visa » dans « dernière date de visa » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, terminologie

Dans un texte technique, qu'est-ce que "visa" signifie?

> Constructeur : / Nom : / Date : / Visa :

(c'est un formulaire)

Et encore:

> Le transfert de propriété prend effet à la dernière date de visa requis.

De quel visa s'agit-il? De quelle date? (date de fin de validité du visa?) Peut-être une explication en anglais?

Comment: Avez-vous d'autres exemples? Le premier exemple me laisse penser que *visa* pourrait avoir ici le sens de [*signature*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/visa/82159). Mais le second exemple est pour moi confus, ça ne veut pas dire grand chose, hors contexte.

Comment: Il n'y a pas d'autres exemples. La phrase avec "visa requis" se trouve juste en dessous de ce formulaire. Mais dans un autre fragment du texte, il y a un formulaire similaire mais avec : nom, date et signature. Je pense donc qu'ici, il ne s'agit pas de "signature".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De manière générale, une *signature* atteste qu'une personne a lu un document et est d'accord avec son contenu. Un *[visa](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/visa)* est une sorte de signature motivée. Celui qui donne le visa atteste que le document est conforme à une certaine procédure. Le mot a des sens juridiques précis dans certains contextes, par exemple :

- un inspecteur met son visa sur un document pour déclarer la conformité à une norme ou un règlement ;
- le visa sur un passeport atteste que le porteur a bien reçu l'autorisation des autorités d'un pays d'entrer dans ce pays (c'est le seul sens de *visa* dans le langage courant aujourd'hui) ;
- le visa de la censure sur une œuvre atteste que cette œuvre est conforme aux règles qui restreignent le droit d'expression ;
- le visa d'un acte administratif (par exemple un jugement) énumère les textes de loi, règlements et autres actes juridiques qui ont été pris en considération pour établir cet acte.

Ici, le document doit quelque part établir que quelque chose est conforme à un règlement ou à un cahier des charges. Le visa du constructeur signifie qu'il déclare la chose conforme. « Date de visa requis » sous-entend que la conformité doit être attestée par plusieurs personnes ; le transfert de propriété a lieu lorsque toutes les personnes qui devaient le faire ont déclaré la chose conforme. Par exemple, s'il s'agit d'un contrat de construction immobilière, la phrase signifierait que la propriété du bâtiment est transférée du constructeur à l'acquéreur lorsque l'architecte, l'inspecteur des travaux publics, l'électricien, etc., ont tous déclaré le bâtiment conforme.

Answer (score 2):

Un *document* en latin peut se traduire en latin par [carta](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=carta) ou [charta](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=charta) selon le dictionnaire [Gaffiot](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php). Et un *document vu* par *charta visa*, *visa* étant ici le [participe passé de voir](http://www.dicolatin.com/FR/LAK/0/VIDERE/index.htm).

Dans votre exemple donc, 'visa' peut simplement se traduire par 'vu' - cette action de voir étant associée à l'approbation d'une personne qualifiée.